# Numerical issue with softmax regression implementation on MNIST

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, one-hot-encoding, softmax

I'm having numpy numerical issues with my implementation of softmax regression/multiclass logistic regression on the MNIST dataset.

The numpy exp and log numerical issue goes away when I divide the x values by 255 (normalization). I'm confident that I'm correctly implementing the lost and gradient functions.

I tried writing my softmax as `np.exp(z - max(z)) / np.sum(np.exp(z - max(z)), axis = 1, keepdims=True)` but it was still giving errors in with np.log dividing by 0 in cross-entropy error.

Is there something I'm missing that is causing the softmax regression to fail when running MNIST data with x values ranging from 0 to 255 but works on x values ranging from with 0 to 1

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import urlopen
import gzip


#[['http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'],
# ['http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz']]:

def getMNISTXData(url):
  streamed_file = urlopen(url)
  with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=streamed_file) as f:
    # first 4 bytes is a magic number
    magic_number = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
    # second 4 bytes is the number of images
    image_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
    # third 4 bytes is the row count
    row_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
    # fourth 4 bytes is the column count
    column_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
    # rest is the image pixel data, each pixel is stored as an unsigned byte
    # pixel values are 0 to 255
    image_data = f.read()
    #reshape the values to between 0 and 1 instead of 0 to 255
    #divide by 255 is done for numerical stability, otherwise numpy exp will overflow
    images = np.frombuffer(image_data, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((image_count, row_count *  column_count))
    return images



def getMNISTYData(url):
  streamed_file = urlopen(url)
  with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=streamed_file) as f:
    # first 4 bytes is a magic number
    magic_number = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
    # second 4 bytes is the number of labels
    label_count = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), 'big')
    # rest is the label data, each label is stored as unsigned byte
    # label values are 0 to 9
    label_data = f.read()
    labels = np.frombuffer(label_data, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((label_count, 1))
    return labels

x_train_url = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
y_train_url = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
x_train = getMNISTXData(x_train_url)
y_train = getMNISTYData(y_train_url)
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(x_train[1].reshape((28,28)), cmap='gray_r')
plt.show()


x_test_url = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
y_test_url = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz'
x_test = getMNISTXData(x_test_url)
y_test = getMNISTYData(y_test_url)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(x_test[0].reshape((28,28)), cmap='gray_r')
plt.show()

#Indicator fuction
#returns array with index y being 1 and 0 for all other
def indicatorFunc(y, size = 10):
  indicatorArray = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.uint8)
  indicatorArray[y] = 1
  return indicatorArray

#Gets the 1{yi = k} vector for each y, final result is matrix.
#each row is the 1{yi = k}
def oneHotEncodeMatrix(y_data):
  OHTResult = np.zeros((len(y_data), 10))
  for index in range(len(y_data)):
    OHTResult[index] = indicatorFunc(y_data[index])
  return OHTResult

#gets the WX+b value
def calcZ(x_data, weight, bias):
  return np.dot(x_data, weight) + bias

#calculates softmax for values for each xi
def softmaxMatrix(z):
  #numerator is the exp(wx+b) for each class for each data
  #denom is the sum of exp(wx+b)
  #dividing them we get softmax for each class in for each x
  return np.exp(z - np.max(z), dtype=np.float128) / np.sum(np.exp(z - np.max(z), dtype=np.float128), axis = 1, keepdims = True, dtype=np.float128)

#calculates the gradient of W and b used for gradient Descent
def calculateNLossGradient(x, error):
  #first element of the tuple is the gradient of weight: Summation i=1 to n 1/n * xi(P(yi=k|xi,w,b) - 1{yi = k})
  #second element is the gradient of bias: Summation i=1 to n  1/n * (P(yi=k|xi,w,b) - 1{yi = k})
  return (1/x.shape[0] * np.dot(x.T, error), 1/x.shape[0] * np.sum(error, axis = 0, dtype=np.float128))


def calculateNCrossEntropyLoss(yOneHotEnc, softmax, z):
  #calculates the cross entropy loss for current weight and bias on training data
  #return np.mean(-np.sum(yOneHotEnc * np.log(softmax, dtype=np.float128), axis = 1, dtype=np.float128), dtype=np.float128)
  return np.mean(-np.log(np.sum(yOneHotEnc * softmax, axis = 1, dtype=np.float128), dtype=np.float128))

def MulticlassLRGradientDescent(x_data, y_data, learning_rate = 0.5, min_tolerance = 0.6):
  #create weight and softmax values
  modelWeight = np.zeros((784,10), dtype=np.float128)
  modelBias = np.zeros(10, dtype=np.float128)
  yOHE = oneHotEncodeMatrix(y_data)
  zVal = calcZ(x_data, modelWeight, modelBias)
  softmaxVal = softmaxMatrix(zVal)
  errVal = softmaxVal - yOHE
  #calculate initial Cross entropy loss
  lossValue = calculateNCrossEntropyLoss(yOHE, softmaxVal, zVal)

  print('Starting Fitting Model')

  #loop until min_tolerance is reached on cross entropy loss
  while (lossValue > min_tolerance):
    print(lossValue)

    #gets gradient for weight and bias
    weightGradient, biasGradient = calculateNLossGradient(x_data, errVal)
    #update weight and bias
    modelWeight -= learning_rate * weightGradient
    modelBias -= learning_rate * biasGradient
    #calculates softmax for next iter
    zVal = calcZ(x_data, modelWeight, modelBias)
    softmaxVal = softmaxMatrix(zVal)
    errVal = softmaxVal - yOHE


    #calculates new loss on updated weight and bias
    lossValue = calculateNCrossEntropyLoss(yOHE, softmaxVal, zVal)



  return (lossValue, modelWeight, modelBias)

#predicts the integer based on 28x28 MNIST data
def predict(x_data, weight, bias):
  zVal = calcZ(x_data, weight, bias)
  softmaxVal = softmaxMatrix(zVal)
  return np.argmax(softmaxVal, axis=1)

#calculates the correct prediction rate of the model
def calculatePredictError(y_data, predictOutput):
  correctNum = 0
  for index in range(len(y_data)):
    if y_data[index] == predictOutput[index]:
      correctNum += 1
  return correctNum / len(y_data)

#doing some test
print(MulticlassLRGradientDescent(x_train, y_train))
result = MulticlassLRGradientDescent(x_train, y_train)
print(calculatePredictError(predict(x_test, result[1], result[2]), y_test))
```